# Method or delegate parameters do not match delegate parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, action, func

I'm doing some asynchronous caching and I'm using a simple Action callback to let the rest of the system know when the caching is complete.

---

The entry point (the line causing the error):

```
this.StartCoroutine<Action>(SceneUtils.CacheSceneNames, PopulateButtons);
```

Coroutine method:

```
public static IEnumerator CacheSceneNames(Action completedCallback) {}
```

Callback method:

```
private void PopulateButtons() {}
```

And finally, the method that starts the coroutine:

```
public static Coroutine StartCoroutine<T>(this MonoBehaviour extends, Func<IEnumerator, T> method, T value) {}
```

---

As far as I can tell all of the parameter and return types are correct, however I'm getting the following error:

```
error CS0123: A method or delegate `CacheSceneNames(System.Action)' parameters do not match delegate `System.Func<System.Collections.IEnumerator,System.Action>(System.Collections.IEnumerator)' parameters
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Could this be a covariance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to specify `Func<T, IEnumerator> method` instead of `Func<IEnumerator, T> method` in the parameter list of `StartCoroutine<T>`.

It's `Func<T, TResult>`: the return type is the last type parameter - and your `CacheSceneNames` takes a parameter of `Action` (`T`) and returns `IEnumerator`.

Comment: 10/10, thanks for correcting my silly mistake. Will flag as correct when I'm allowed!